# Did Data ever have an issue with his head being 500 years older than his body?

Tags: star-trek

According to [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Data), Data was less than 50 years old when he "died". However, in the double episode [Time's Arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%27s_Arrow_%28Star_Trek%3a_The_Next_Generation%29), we see that Data's head was left in a cave (undiscovered, sadly) for 500 years. It was later reattached, of course.

But that makes his head 500 years older than his body! Was this ever referred to in later episodes? I would have thought that it being left for in a dusty cave for five centuries might cause problems.

Comment: I'm guessing at the very least that it voided the warranty. Plus, [Bender's head](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender_Bending_Rodr%C3%ADguez) has his beat by 555 years.

Comment: @gnovice: indeed, that (Bender's head) is what made me think of this question... :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Data's head was not active during those 500 years, and it was in conditions that were conductive to preservation.

Data was also constructed to last a very long time - he refers to himself at one point as effectively immortal.

During his head's time inactive in the cave, it doesn't significantly change - his positronic brain is shut off and doesn't alter any pathways, which I believe would be the only potential source for problems.

In short, no, he suffers no apparent ill effect, and it isn't brought up again.